# TemplateDoesNotExist at / basicapp/index.html

Tags: django, django-forms

I tried creating basic forms with django from a direct example from Python and Django Full Stack Web Developer Bootcamp.  I got the error below.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
basicapp/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
basicapp/index.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  basicapp.views.index
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

Python Version: 3.11.0

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Django\Django_forms\basic_forms\templates,\basicapp\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\basicapp\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\basicapp\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

This is my **setting.py **

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates,")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-bdh2@$^s84&+%qn^atqa+xjz8@7&g=(m2^!5j$f#$o=4+7jb5s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    "basicapp",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'basic_forms.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,`
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms

# Create your views here.

    def index(request):
        return render(request,"basicapp/index.html")


    def form_name_view(request):
        form = forms.FormName()

    return render(request,"basicapp/form_page.html",{"form:Form":form})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("", views.index,name="index"),
        path("formpage/", views.form_name_view, name="form_name"),
    ]
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class FormName(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()`
    email=forms.EmailField()
    text=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `templates does not exist` because you have added `comma` in `TEMPLATE_DIR`.

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates") #let's remove comma from here.
```

And now this will work!